# How to get the threshold from PrecisionRecallDisplay?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, roc, auc, precision-recall

My goal is to tune the Classifier with probability `predict_proba() < threshold`. Therefore, I need to get the threshold.

The problem is `sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay` do not give me the threshold.

[scikit-learn.org](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py)

The code:

```
# Model Definition
rf_pipe_tuned = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('composer', composer),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(
        max_depth=17, max_features=9, min_samples_split= 7, n_estimators=27
    ))
])

# Model Training
rf_pipe_tuned.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
print("done")

def isolate():
    display = PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator(
        estimator=rf_pipe_tuned, X=X_test, y=y_test, name="RandomForestClassifier",
        pos_label="Attrited Customer"
    )
    _ = display.ax_.set_title("2-class Precision-Recall curve")

isolate()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrecisionRecallDisplay()` is just a very basic wrapper for `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve()`. The latter returns numpy arrays for precision, recall and thresholds, which allow easy vectorized handling, e.g.:

```
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(target_test, probabilities)
f1_scores = 2 * recall * precision / (recall + precision)
best_thresh = thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [@dx2-66's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/596826/378211), here is a complete code example that also draws the point where the threshold lies:

```
from sklearn.metrics import PrecisionRecallDisplay, precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score

# ...
y_true = ...
y_pred = ...
pos_label = 1  # replace with your positive label
name = "My Model". # replace with your desired model name

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=pos_label)
f1_scores = 2 * recall * precision / (recall + precision)
best_th_ix = np.nanargmax(f1_scores)
best_thresh = thresholds[best_th_ix]
average_precision = average_precision_score(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=pos_label)
display = PrecisionRecallDisplay(
    precision=precision,
    recall=recall,
    average_precision=average_precision,
    estimator_name=name,
    pos_label=pos_label)
display.plot(name=name)
display.ax_.set_title("Test Data")
display.ax_.plot(recall[best_th_ix], precision[best_th_ix], "ro", label=f"f1max (th = {best_thresh:.2f})")
display.ax_.legend()
```